# Bash regular expression, multiple criteria

Tags: regex, bash, grep

```
echo $list | egrep '^a[^aeiou][0-9]'
```

What should I do with the regex to meet the following requirement:

> Start with an 'a', second char can't be a vowel, and there should be at least one number in the name of the file.

My problem obviously is making the number thing right.

Comment: This is a good exercise to work out for yourself. You should keep trying. Try asking yourself this question: Seeing that the regex you wrote doesn't work, what does it match? Can you explain it in precise words what that regex does?

Comment: Another way to attack the problem is to break it into pieces. Try just the third piece: can you write a regex that checks if a string contains at least one number? Ignore the first two criteria, just handle the third.

Comment: 'My problem obviously is making the number thing right.' obviously not : `a9` adheres to the rules, but is not matched.

Comment: you want like this `echo $list | egrep  [:alpha:][0-9]`

Comment: Hint: you need to use the `|` operator in your regular expression to deal with the multiple scenarios. Either that, or a lookahead with Perl-mode `-P` enabled (but that's probably overkill in this case).

Comment: Well i solved it but i dont think it is the most optimal way:
echo $list | egrep '^a[^aeiou]' | egrep '[0-9]{1,}'

Comment: how about `echo $list | egrep '^a[^aeiou0-9][0-9]'` ?

Comment: Do you mean bash regular expression or grep? `grep` is not bash and bash has its own regex engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Well i solved it but i dont think it is the most optimal way: `echo $list | egrep '^a[^aeiou]' | egrep '[0-9]{1,}'`

Note, you should quote your variable: `echo "$list" | ...`

That's a fine way to go about it. The 2nd expression can be simpler: all you need to match is a single digit, so you can drop `{1,}`

Another couple of possibilities:

```
list="foo
alpha
a9
aa0
alpha1"

grep '[0-9]' <<< "$list" | grep '^a[^aeiou]'    # same as yours
grep -E '^a([0-9]|[^aeiou].*[0-9])' <<< "$list"
grep -P '^a(?=.*\d)[^aeiou]' <<< "$list"
while read line; do 
    [[ $line =~ ^a([0-9]|[^aeiou].*[0-9]) ]] && echo "$line" 
done <<< "$list"
```

All those output

```
a9
alpha1
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your question title mentions bash regular expressions, here's how to do it using those instead of `grep`:

```
while IFS= read -r name; do 
    [[ "$name" =~ ^a([0-9]|[^aeiou].*[0-9]) ]] && printf "%s\n" "$name"; 
done <<< "$list"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "$list" | egrep '^a[^aeiou]\(.*[0-9].*\)?'
```

Basically you were almost there, the missing piece was to match the other characters around the number you want to match.

Comment: That can't match "a1"

Comment: That's true, if that's a requirement you can do echo $list | egrep '^a[^aeiou]\(.*[0-9].*\)?'